# How to use Graph (or another MS API) to retrieve an Azure Enterprise App Object ID

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-rest-api

Currently writing an Azure function using Python and REST calls that will:

1. Get a service principal (passed as a parameter)
2. Generate a new secret for said service principal
3. Get a keyvault (passed as a parameter)
4. Add access policy to kevault to allow the storage of the new secret
5. Set the secret in the keyvault with an appropriate name (supplied as a parameter)

I've got it working down to step 4.  For step 4, I'm using the following API:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/vaults/updateaccesspolicy

The REST payload is asking for an objectID, which turns on to be the objectID of the ENTERPRISE APP, and not the application registration.  I've been able to successfully set the secret using that with test code.

My question is - how do you retrieve the Enterprise App's Object ID?  I've been looking at the Graph API, but the only endpoint I can find is this one:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

This endpoint retrieves the application registration object, not the enterprise application object. How do I get the Enterprise app object id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enterprise app is service principal in Microsoft Graph.

Use [List servicePrincipals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) with a `filter` query parameters to get it.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/serviceprincipals?$filter=appId eq '{client id of your  application registration}'
```

Comment: That will return the object ID of the application registration, which is different than the enterprise application object ID.  I need to return the object ID of the Enterprise app.

Comment: @ScottFischer It's not true. [List applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) is used to get application registration. [List servicePrincipals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) is used to get enterprise application. Please check. If you still have concern, share some screenshots of your Graph response and your enterprise application / application registration on Azure portal.

Comment: Allen - sorry, haven't been able to test this yet.  However, are you confusing this with AAD Graph?  I put in a MS ticket.  They informed me that the functionality I'm looking for doesn't exist in Microsoft Graph yet, but does exist in AAD Graph.

Comment: @ScottFischer I'm pretty sure Microsoft Graph supports it.

Comment: I just got around to testing this, and you are absolutely correct.  I was confused by the difference between an Enterprise app (what appears in the portal) and the REST API documentation for an Entrerprise App (which the API docs refer to as a service principal). Thanks for the clarification!